# celery and how to send task

Tags: python, celery

I am sending a task like the below.....

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery()
celery.send_task('order_celery.order_worker', (order,))
```

From the worker log..this is what I get....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 445, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'order_celery.order_worker'
```

here is my worker order_celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://%s:6379/0'%redis_host,backend='redis://%s:6379/0'%redis_host)

@app.task
def order_worker(order):
   return True
```

Why will celery not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order_celery.py should be in your PYTHONPATH, you should run your worker in like [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#running-the-celery-worker-server):

```
celery -A order_worker worker --loglevel=info
```

Comment: all files are in the same dir/folder.